# How can I make it possible for users to upload several files in a shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny

I know I have to use the fileInput function but I want users to be able to upload just one file, or two, or three or several, and then perform the underlying code to those files. 
Then I would like the user to be able to download the resulting file, but that I think I know how to do.
Thanks in advance for any answers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Uploading many files in Shiny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36850114/uploading-many-files-in-shiny)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do believe that [this](https://gist.github.com/stephlocke/c3299992ef3ac3efe1f978bd1cb0b4b2) should put you in the right direction, worked like a charm for me. The basic logic is to enable the `multiple` flag in `fileInput` and traverse through the list of files in your server function.

```r
library(shiny)
library(data.table)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Multiple file uploads"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fileInput("csvs",
                label="Upload CSVs here",
                multiple = TRUE)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      textOutput("count")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  mycsvs<-reactive({
    rbindlist(lapply(input$csvs$datapath, fread),
              use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE)
  })
  output$count <- renderText(nrow(mycsvs()))
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```